# Transform a normal desktop menu to a select option menu ( for mobile versions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

I have a normal menu for desktop versions with 3 levels.

And for smartphone and tablet versions Im trying to use a normal select option menu, because I think that works fine on these devices.

So Im trying to transform my normal desktop menu to a select option menu, but Im not having sucess doing this.

In my normal menu I use href to put my links, in select option Im trying with value but its not working.

Do you know how can I do this?

My example: http://jsfiddle.net/jcak/33g70fae/2/

This  is my html:

```
<section id="menu-container">   
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul class="menu_desktop">
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span>Institution</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="<?php setHome()?>/institution/values">Our Values</a></li>
                    <li><a class="fancybox_pdf" href="<?php setHome()?>/institution/team">Our Team</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>   
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span>Our Work</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li ><a href="<?php setHome()?>/works/webdesign">Web Design</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="<?php setHome()?>/works/webdesign/posters">Posters</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php setHome()?>/works/webdesign/websites">Websites</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li ><a href="<?php setHome()?>/works/3d">3d Modeling</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="<?php setHome()?>/works/3d/blender">Blender</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php setHome()?>/works/3d/studiomax">3d studio max</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li ><a href="<?php setHome()?>/works/video">Video</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="<?php setHome()?>/works/video/premiere">Premiere</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span>Contacts</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="<?php setHome()?>/contacts/north">North Seaat</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php setHome()?>/contacts/south">South Seat</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>            
        </ul> 
        <select id="select"> 
            <option value="<?php setHome()?>" selected="selected">Menu</option> 
            <option value="<?php setHome()?>/agrupamento/institution">Institution</option> 
            <option value="">Our Work</option> 
            <option value="">Web Design</option> 
            <option value="">Posters</option> 
            <option value="">Website</option>  
            <option value="">3d modeling</option> 
            <option value="">blender</option> 
            <option value="">3d studio max</option> 
            <option value="">Video</option>
            <option value="">Premiere</option>
        </select>  
    </nav>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#menu-container{
    width:100%;
    height:72px;
    float:left;
    float:left;
    background:green;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;  
}

#menu{
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}

.menu_desktop{display:none;}

#select{margin-top:20px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Js

use on change listener on select menu

```
document.getElementById('select').onchange = function(){
//based on the values u give in options prepare the url n send it 
//to window.location.href
    window.location.href = this.value;
}
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/c42ovrt5/

output http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/c42ovrt5/embedded/result/

Using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select').on('change',function(){
        window.location.href = this.value;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution works fine. But Im with another doubt maybe you can help me again. For example in my desktop menu you can see that I have links with "javascript:void(0);", wich means that these links aren´t really links to other pages. They exist as if they are only titles for submenus. But on mobile when I click in my select option menu, my "Institution, Our Works, Contacts" appears like as if they are an option, allowing its selection. This happens because I have this links as <option>. Do you know how can I have this links only as a title without allow to select them?

Comment: in that case what u can do is add all options to the menu.Keep the ones that are top level disabled n for others give some spaces so that they look like suboptions. **fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/58ufxd50/**